# Creating barh chart in python based on specific group such as category action and display all names of the movies based on the duration

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I would like to create multiple barh charts based on a genre category in the movies.csv with the name display on the vertical axis and the duration of the movies being displayed in the horizontal axis for all movies genre with the movies that belong to that category. Currently the charts are very hard to read with all of the name of movies overlapping one another.

```
Df.groupby['columnName'].plot(x = row_Values_of_columnA, y = row_Named_of_columnB, kind='barh')
....
```

I tried the plots built into the grouby but the charts are not neat nor easy to read let alone get information from it.

```
#import all the needed libraries

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the dataframe

filename = imdb_1000.csv

movies = pd.read_csv(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/imdb_1000.csv)

movies.head()

#create the groups I would like to see

movies_group = movies.groupby(['genre','title'])

movies_average = movies_group.mean()

#display the groups created

movies_average

#sort the values of the groups

movies_average['duration'].sort_values(ascending=False)

#create the visualization

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# create a barh chart

movies_average['duration'].plot(ax=ax,kind='barh')
```

The desired output is within a genre like action show all of the names of the movies based on their duration in descending order in a barh chart

Comment: [link](http:/bit.ly/imdbratings) location to get the filename. A second / will need to be added after http: to access the file since it was flagged by the system for the link to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need a groupby. Here's the plot for "Crime" genre.

```
df = pd.read_csv('imdb_1000.csv')
df.loc[df['genre'] == 'Crime', ['title', 'star_rating']].sort_values(by='star_rating').plot(x='title', y='star_rating', kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make a bar graph for *each* genre, then yes, use groupby.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('imdb_1000.csv')

print(df['genre'].unique())
for key, grp in df.groupby('genre'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    grp.sort_values(by='duration').plot(x='title', y='duration', kind='barh', legend=False, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(key.title())
    ax.set_xlabel('Duration')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I just tried that it semi serves my purposes but the barh created still to hard to understand since all names of the movies are overlapping. is there a way to explicit determine the size of the chart using plt or would I need to use a blank canvas such as fig...

Comment: I wanted to utilize the grouby by to be able to recreate subplots using each genre instead of manually have to rewrite the code for each genre category to make as modular as possible.

Comment: Using the idea you proposed @brentertainer this the best I came up with but the name of the movies aren't appearing I believe the row are in there a way around that.                                                                                                                            
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
movies.loc[movies['genre'] == 'Crime', ['title', 'duration']].sort_values(by='duration').plot(ax=ax, kind='barh')

Comment: @Dino I feel the remarks in my edit answer the question (in the context of groupby). If that is the case, please upvote and/or select as answer. If not, please refine the question.

Comment: How do I upvote? I am relatively new to posting question in stackoverflow. I am generally directed here when I google something and people have had the same problem in the past

Comment: @Dino. I see, thanks for contributing to the community! Near the top and to the left of each response, you should see up and down arrows (next to the total upvote/downvote) count. You can click on those arrows to upvote/downvote. There should also be a gray checkmark under those arrows. Click that to accept the answer.

Comment: @Dino I also edited my response one last time to include what you're trying to do with `plt.subplots`.

Comment: thank you very much I tried to upvote but it said that I would have to more than 15 to actually affect the vote. One last question how did you format your response to appear as a code block instead of a comment?

Comment: @Dino Do a web search for "markdown code fences" and you should find instructions on how to use triple backticks to format code.